# Show that for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we have $\kappa ! = 2^{\kappa}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Synopsis**

For this exercise, we are asked to show that for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we have $\kappa ! = 2^{\kappa}$, where $\kappa! = \text{card}\{f | \text{$f$ is a permutation of $K$}\}$, and a permutation of $K$ is described as a bijection from $K$ onto $K$. My idea of a solution was to try to show that $\kappa! \leq 2^{\kappa} \leq \kappa!$. The first part of doing so, showing $\kappa! \leq 2^{\kappa}$, was easy since $\{f | \text{$f$ is a permutation of $K$}\} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(K \times K)$, and $2^{\kappa \cdot \kappa} = 2^{\kappa}$. But I've been having some trouble showing that $2^{\kappa} \leq \kappa!$. I was thinking of finding an injection between ${}^K2$ and $\{f | \text{$f$ is a permutation of $K$}\}$ where $|K| = \kappa$, but I wasn't quite sure how I would transform the range of $2$ of a function in ${}^K2$ to the range $K$ in the function defining the factorial with it still being an injection and well-defined. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** For any $A \subseteq X$ with $|A| \neq 1$ you can construct a bijection
$$f_A: X \to X$$ such that
$$A:= \{ x \in X : f_A(x) \neq x \}$$
i.e. $X \backslash A$ is the set of fixed points of $f$.

This shows that
$$
\left| \{ A \subset X : |A| \neq 1 \} \right| \leq \kappa !
$$
and it is not hard to show that $2^\kappa \leq \left| \{ A \subset X : |A| \neq 1 \} \right|$.

**P.S.** It is probably easier to construct for each $A \subseteq X$ a bijection
$$
f_A : X \times X \to X \times X 
$$
such that
$$
\{ z \in X \times X : f(z)=z \}= \{ (a,a) : a \in A \} 
$$

[or $A= \{ x \in X : f_A(x,y)=(x,y) \forall y \in X \}$.]

Comment: Is $2^{\kappa} = \left| \{ A \subset K : |A| \neq 1 \} \right|$ since $ \left| \{ A \subset K : |A| \neq 1 \} \right| = 2^{\kappa} - \kappa = 2^{\kappa}$?  Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: I know that subtraction isn't necessarily well defined for infinite cardinals, but since $\kappa$ is strictly less than $2^{\kappa}$, then by the absorption principle, $2^{\kappa}= 2^{\kappa} + \kappa$.

Comment: @mijucik Yes it is. For infinite cardinals, $a+b = \max \{a,b \}$. Then $2^\kappa = \max \{ 2^\kappa - \kappa, \kappa \}$ and $2^\kappa \neq \kappa$.

Comment: @mijucik Alternatelly, you can trivially show that $2^{\kappa} \leq (2^{\kappa}-\kappa)+(2^{\kappa}-\kappa)=(2^{\kappa}-\kappa)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Break a permutation into two parts, some elements will retain their positions and others will permute. Now let us put permutations into equivalence classes if two permutations have the same fixed elements. We can have 2^k such classes. So we can see that no. of permutations is greater than no. of such classes as no classes are empty.